# Highcharts and JSON

Tags: json, highcharts

Let me know how to declare multiple data in Y because my script doesn't work.

My JSON file is:

```
[{"metier":"Administratif","annee2005":182373,"annee2006":188153,"annee2007":194636},
{"metier":"Igenieur","annee2005":9140,"annee2006":9483,"annee2007":4321},
{"metier":"Chef de chantier","annee2005":25118,"annee2006":29417,"annee2007":32081},
{"metier":"Commercial","annee2005":13122,"annee2006":16294,"annee2007":17706}]
```

My Javascript is

```
$.getJSON('dataTest.json', function(data) {

    var output = [];

    $.each(data,function(i,d){
        output.push(
        {
            name: d.metier,
            y: [d.annee2005,d.annee2006]
        }
        );
    });

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart:{
            type:'column'
        },
        xAxis:{
            type:'category'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Métiers',
            data: output
        }
            ]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In `output.y` you have array of two values but it must be one value for y, you need create 2 series for output 2 graphics

Comment: Like this ? <br/> output.push(
  {
            name: d.metier,
            y: d.annee2005
        },
  {
            name: d.metier,
            y: d.annee2006
        }
  
  );